# Multiple layout pages sharing same headers

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a site that makes use of 3 different Layout pages. On each page, the top section is duplicated. That is, the meta tags, the css file references, some google analytics links. They're all copied and pasted to each layout page.

What concept can I use in my MVC layout, to allow me to have all of this in a single page, and then 'included' on all layout pages? I was hoping to have some form of '_global.cshtml' file, that I can just include on each layout page. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in each layout page you can declare a new layout, and point each one to a global layout.

So within each layout you would write

```
@{
    Layout = "path/to/global/layout"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can achieve this in the site.master file.

Ex in site.master:

```
<%@ Master Language="CS" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Site.Master.cs" Inherits="Site" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
--meta here
--js files here
--css files here
--title
</head>

<body>
--your navigation/header
<form runat="server" method="post">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/> -- this is where the content of every page appended.
</form>
--your footer
</body>
</html>
```

In your aspx, you must wrap your codes inside the asp:content with the attribute "contentplaceholder" = the id of your contenplaceholder in the site.master file

Ex in aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="MySite" Language="CS" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="MyAspx.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyAspx" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID = "MainContent">
<div>
 <h1>My ASPX CONTENT</h1>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: This is mvc. he isn't using any aspx files.